# Addition of Textbox Values which having same name & id ( Textbox getting for loop as per database )

Tags: javascript, laravel

Good Afternoon... I am trying to do the addition of textbox value and show in total textbox using onBlur but not able to do the same. Textbox are generated using foreach loop as per buffaloID base on database which having same name and id. ( Ref. Attached Image) For first textbox, the function gives the value but for next textboxes, not able to get the same.

My Modal Table Code.

```
@foreach ($buffalodata as $item )
 <tr> 
    <td>{{$item->buffaloID}}</td>
    <td><input type="number" id="eachmorningmilk" name="eachmorningmilk" value="00"></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="eacheveningmilk" name="eacheveningmilk" value="00"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="eachtotalmilk" name="eachtotalmilk" value="00" readonly></td>
  </tr>
 @endforeach
```

JavaScript Code for Function to run onblur

```
$("#eachmorningmilk").blur(function(){

                    eachbmorning = parseInt($("#addmilkbuffalo #eachmorningmilk").val());

                    eachbevening = parseInt($("#addmilkbuffalo #eacheveningmilk").val());

                    var eachbuffalototalmilk = eachbmorning + eachbevening;


                    document.getElementById('eachtotalmilk').value=eachbuffalototalmilk;

                })
```

Ref. Images

[image]

[image]

Comment: fyi, `id` attributes _must_ be unique - yours are not

Comment: You can append **eachmorningmilk** with  **buffaloID** to create unique textbox.

Comment: Thank for Quick reply..... I m new to coding and self learner. Can u give some hints on code ...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please use the onchange method and assign unique id and name to each field. You can refer to the below code and it will work.

**HTML**

```
<tr> 
<td>{{$item->buffaloID}}</td>
<td><input type="number" id="eachmorningmilk{{$item->buffaloID}}" name="eachmorningmilk{{$item->buffaloID}}" onchange="totalmilk({{$item->buffaloID}})" value="00"></td>
<td><input type="number" id="eacheveningmilk{{$item->buffaloID}}" onchange="totalmilk({{$item->buffaloID}})" name="eacheveningmilk{{$item->buffaloID}}" value="00"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="eachtotalmilk{{$item->buffaloID}}" name="eachtotalmilk{{$item->buffaloID}}" value="00" readonly></td>
```

**JS**

```
function totalmilk(id){
 var morningmilk = "#eachmorningmilk"+id;
 var eveningmilk = "#eacheveningmilk"+id;
 var totalmilk = "eachtotalmilk"+id;
 eachbmorning = parseInt($(morningmilk).val());
 eachbevening = parseInt($(eveningmilk).val());
 var eachbuffalototalmilk = eachbmorning + eachbevening;
 document.getElementById(totalmilk).value=eachbuffalototalmilk; 
}
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: totalmilk is not defined

Comment: Can you please past the error message and also let me know where you have added above code?

Comment: JS added in script tag after all required script are loaded. Now giving error. = "Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffalo is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onchange ". Blade file showing red error on onchange="------". Ref Attached image